# ORACLE APEX - Download to .CSV (null values shown as - are missing) problem

Tags: oracle, csv, null, oracle-apex

I recently upgraded from APEX 5.0.3 to APEX 20.2 and since then I have an issue when downloading a table as a .CSV file

The tables have many columns and each column contains either text, (decimal) numbers or Null values that are shown in APEX as **-** (dash) with the APEX functionality (Attributes => Appearance => Show Null Values AS - )

**Col6**, **Col8** and **Col9** show **-** (dashes)

The table below is just an example with 10 columns (separated with | (pipe)) to give you an idea.

**Example table:**

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 | Col6 | Col7 | Col8 | Col9 | Col10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Max | Muster | 1500 | USD | 2.25 | - | 13.02.2021 | - | - | A |
| Felix | Muster | 2300 | CHF | 3.25 | 1 | 26.07.2021 | IN | CN | D |
| Moritz | Max | 4500 | EUR | 4.20 | - | 16.08.2021 | - | - | C |

**CSV Output:**

```
Max,Muster,1500,USD,2.25,,13.02.2021,,,A

Felix,Muster,2300,CHF,3.25,1,26.07.2021,IN,CN,D

Moritz,Max,4500,EUR,4.20,,16.08.2021,,,C
```

Standard download in APEX 20.2 loses the dashes!! I wonder why.

**I would expect the following result in the .CSV file:**

```
Max,Muster,1500,USD,2.25,**-**,13.02.2021,**-**,**-**,A

Felix,Muster,2300,CHF,3.25,1,26.07.2021,IN,CN,D

Moritz,Max,4500,EUR,4.20,**-**,16.08.2021,**-**,**-**,C
```

Does anyone have a solution for it. We have many reports with up to a 100 columns and we need the dashes in the file. I do not want to add the dash afterwards in the .CSV file nor would I replace the - with any other (special) character.

Best regards,

Thomas

Comment: how are you downloading to CSV ? Are you using the interactive grid property of download to csv ( Actions --> Download --> CSV ) ? Or you use a PL/SQL process for it ?

Comment: hi roberto. 
i am using Actions --> Download --> CSV
with apex 5.0.3 it was working just fine

Comment: Hi Elch007. That is the problem. In Apex 5 it was actually different how it works. Since APEX 19, I think, when you press download, the slash is not part of the column, because it is an attribute of the report itself to show something when the value is null. There is no easy solution for you inside APEX, as you are using the AJAX attributes of the report object, which are tricky to deal with. I would prefer to use an standard download link with a function, then you can do everything inside the function. But in this case, you have to change all the pages affected.

Comment: there were so many changes in the AJAX code regarding the IG and IR ( Interactive Grid and Interactive Report ). Actually , how it was working before it was a bug, because you were downloading data which does not exist in the database. That is why it was fixed in recent versions

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, displaying a dash is exactly that: *displaying* a dash. It is not contained in the table (column value is `NULL`).

If you wanted to export a dash, then you'd have to modify report's query and literally type what you want to export instead (using the NVL function), e.g.

```
select empno, 
       ename,
       nvl(to_char(comm), '-') comm   --> this
from emp
```

**However**: note that - just as my example shows - you might need to apply another function, such as `TO_CHAR` because dash is a **string** while `comm` column (in Scott's sample `EMP` table) is a `NUMBER`.

I've just tried it, and yes - it works (dashes are exported).

Furthermore, pay attention to what you do. If you export numbers along with dashes, you won't be able to perform any calculations (e.g. if you open the CSV file in MS Excel).

---

In your case, it would be

```
select col1,
       col2, 
       nvl(to_char(col6), '-') col6,   --> NVL + TO_CHAR, as col6 contains numbers 
       nvl(col8, '-') col8             --> just NVL, as col8 contains strings
from your_table
```

Comment: with apex 5.0.3 it was working just fine. i wonder why it's not anymore with version 20.2.

i understand what you are saying and i appreciate your solution. 

i have at least 20 tables and some of them have almost a 100 columns and i would have to fix all of them just for this :-)

well maybe there is no other way around it, so i've got to do this.

Comment: As I said on top, it was a bug in that version. You can't download something to a file when it does not exist as data in the database.